# Looping through word array of addresses in MIPS

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, mips, cpu-word

I'm having difficulty looping through the addresses in the "instructions" array. For some reason it assembles and prompts me with "Error in path\ca.asm line 87: Runtime exception at 0x00400060: address out of range 0x00000000" and points to the syscall for the print message code. Can anybody explain why?

```
# Description: Parse MIPS instructions based on opcode and print message

.globl main, print_hex_info #decode_instruction, process_instruction,       # Do not remove this line

# Data for the program goes here
.data
    process: .asciiz "\nNow processing instruction "
    opcode_num: .asciiz "\tThe opcode value is: "
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"

# number of test cases
CASES: .word 5
# array of pointers (addresses) to the instructions
instructions:   .word 0x01095020,       # add $t2, $t0, $t1
                .word 0x1220002C,       # beqz $s1, label
                .word 0x3C011001,       # lw $a0, label($s0)
                .word 0x24020004,       # li $v0, 4
                .word 0x08100002        # j label

inst_0:     .asciiz "\tR-Type Instruction\n"
inst_other: .asciiz "\tUnsupported Instruction\n"
inst_2_3:   .asciiz "\tUnconditional Jump\n"
inst_4_5:   .asciiz "\tConditional Jump\n"

# You may use this array of labels to print the different instructions type messages
inst_types: .word inst_0, inst_other, inst_2_3, inst_2_3, inst_4_5, inst_4_5

# Code goes here
.text
main:
    # Task 1A: Loop over the array of instructions 
    jal print_hex_info
loop_array:


li $s0, 0
#   Set registers and call: print_hex_info
la $a0, instructions
bge $s0, 3, end_main
 
#   Set registers and call: decode_instruction 

# Print first return value
#   Set registers and call: print_hex_info

# Update branch and index values

j loop_array        # end of loop
    

end_main:
    li $v0, 10      # 10 is the exit program syscall
    syscall         # execute call
###############################################################

## Other procedures here

###############################################################
# Print Message based on opcode type
#
# $a0 - Message to print
# $a1 - Value to print
# Uses $s0: address of string for $a0 (required)
# Uses $s1: value from $a1 (required)
print_hex_info:
    ##### Begin Save registers to Stack
    subi  $sp, $sp, 36
    sw   $ra, 32($sp)
    sw   $s0, 28($sp)
    sw   $s1, 24($sp)
    sw   $s2, 20($sp)
    sw   $s3, 16($sp)
    sw   $s4, 12($sp)
    sw   $s5, 8($sp)
    sw   $s6, 4($sp)
    sw   $s7, 0($sp)
    ##### End Save registers to Stack

    # Now your function begins here
    move $s0, $a0
    move $s1, $a1
    
    li $v0, 4               # print message
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 34              # print address in hex value
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4               # print message
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall

end_print_hex_info:
    ##### Begin Restore registers from Stack
    lw   $ra, 32($sp)
    lw   $s0, 28($sp)
    lw   $s1, 24($sp)
    lw   $s2, 20($sp)
    lw   $s3, 16($sp)
    lw   $s4, 12($sp)
    lw   $s5, 8($sp)
    lw   $s6, 4($sp)
    lw   $s7, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 36
    ##### End Restore registers from Stack
    
    jr $ra
###############################################################
```

Comment: Your first line of code calls `print_hex_info`.  That function expects to receive two parameters in $a0 and $a1.  You did not provide any parameters, so it dereferenced the zero value in $a0.  I suspect that first call is just misplaced.

Comment: Thanks man. I just moved it and now it looks like i'm stuck in an infinite  loop so at least that's some progress lol.

Comment: Use the debugger in MARS (or SPIM) to single-step your code and look at register values.